# North American vs. European Android phones - what's the difference?

Tags: android, gps

I'm wondering if there is a difference between North American and European Android phones in terms of specific region needs?  In other words, do applications work the same on both US and European Androids?  I'm think that GPS-required apps might be one example of where there could be a problem, but I'm not sure...

Thanks, 
Tara

Comment: I would imagine the application would work the same but your standard set of localization concerns would need to be addressed (number/date formatting, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Android is android, regardless of where in the world it is. The only thing that may be different is the carriers and how they handle things. Verizon, AT&T, T-mobile and all may "exist" in europe, but I wouldn't count on them being as big there, if even at all. As R0MANARMY said, the localization would be different and all. GPS apps should work just fine because the GPS *itself* is carrier independent. However, it's useless without Google maps which doesn't store its maps on the phone, they are downloaded in pieces as needed. I don't know how reliable Google Maps is in Europe. As for specific region needs, well, just do your homework and check for any laws and/or restrictions.

So, in short answer; No, there shouldn't a difference between an android phone in the US or Europe, as far as the operating system goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between what bands they can connect to (gsm, 3G, 4G).
You cannot expect an international android phone/tablet to be able to connect to all US carriers.

And Wi-Fi.. US devices are locked from using channels over 11.
This restriction can only be removed if you root your device.